# ObservableCollection not refreshing UI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin and I have problem with refreshing data in Listview. 
I have page with some data and modal where I can modify their value.
Modal communicate with first page by MessagingCenter

Some fragment of my code:

Page:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsList}" HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Result}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Record> recordsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Record> RecordsList
    {
        get { return recordsList; }
        set
        {
            recordsList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RecordsList");
        }
    }
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ObservableCollection<Record>>(this, "update", (records) =>
    {
       RecordsList = records;
    });
```

Modal where I can modify data:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsList, Mode=TwoWay}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Result}" Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Zapisz" Command="{Binding SaveRecordsCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel for modal:

```
        private readonly INavigation _navigation;
    public ObservableCollection<Record> RecordsList { get; set; }
    public ICommand CloseModalCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand SaveRecordsCommand { get; private set; }

    public EditRecordsViewModel(INavigation navigation, ObservableCollection<Record> recordsList)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
        RecordsList = recordsList;
        CloseModalCommand = new Command(async avatar => await CloseModal());
        SaveRecordsCommand = new Command(async avatar => await SaveRecords());
    }

    private async Task CloseModal()
        => await _navigation.PopModalAsync();

    private async Task SaveRecords()
    {
        ProfilRepository.UpdateRecords(RecordsList);
        MessagingCenter.Send<ObservableCollection<Record>>(RecordsList, "update");
        await CloseModal();
    }
```

During debugging RecordList is changed but view is not refreshed, What is wrong with ths code?

Comment: Make sure you fire property changed on the UI thread or only update the RecordsList property on the UI thread. Sending a message through the MessagingCenter doesn't enforce that.

Comment: For maintainability purpose, you should use `nameof`  operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof. That is: `nameof(RecordsList)`.

Comment: Did you set the Datacontext?

Comment: @Cheesebaron - how can i do this, can you tell me?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I did it like this:
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
      RecordsList = records;
});

Dont help, stil Ui is not refreshing.

Comment: Where do you set your DataContext?

Comment: `public ProfilPage ()
{
 InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new ProfilViewModel(Navigation);
}`

BindingContext is working. On this page I have also other properties which can be changed in other modals, and everything is OK. I have problem only with ObservableCollection<Record> in ListView.

Comment: post code for  `ProfilRepository.UpdateRecords`

Comment: @Prateek ProfilRepository.UpdateRecords it is just saving data to database. The problem is with refreshing UI. In ViewModel during debugging RecordsList has correct values, but not in UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the right binding, it should work, I wrote a demo for you and you can check if there is any difference with your code to find out the problem:

In xaml, same as your code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsList}" HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="click to change" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ProfilViewModel model = new ProfilViewModel();
        BindingContext = model;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var RecordsList = new ObservableCollection<Record>();

        RecordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "e" });
        RecordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "f" });
        RecordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "g" });

        MessagingCenter.Send<ObservableCollection<Record>>(RecordsList, "update");
    }
}

public class ProfilViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Record> recordsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Record> RecordsList
    {
        get { return recordsList; }
        set
        {
            recordsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RecordsList");
        }  
    }

    public ProfilViewModel() {


        recordsList = new ObservableCollection<Record>();

        recordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "a" });
        recordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "b" });
        recordsList.Add(new Record { Name = "c" });


        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ObservableCollection<Record>>(this, "update", (records) =>
        {
            RecordsList = records;
        });
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string name { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Some points I think you should check is:

1. Is the value in RecordsList changed before/after your send the `MessagingCenter.Send`. You can add a breakpoint inside `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` to check.
2. Where did you put the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe`, the same as my code inside the  `public ProfilViewModel(){}`?
3. Is your binding right? Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Record` model?

Comment: Thanks!! I forgot about implement iNotifyPropertyChanged interface in my domain model - Record